# How to search for values in chrome heap snapshot?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to scrap data from a website and the values are on a canvas element. The website uses 0 Bytes storage. So I guess the data is stored in Memory. I can take/ save snapshot of
the heap from chrome devtools. Is there anyway to search for numerical values in the snapshot?

Comment: Welcome, have you done any research on that topic, yourself? Please read the documentation about what a good SO question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask